# File not readable after converting to byte array and back

Tags: java, arrays, jms

I have a .tar.gz file that I need to put in a byte array in order to put it onto an IBM JMS queue. The trouble is that after converting to a byte array, when I convert back to a file, my file is no longer readable. Here are the two lines that are reading the file into a JMS Message and then writing the bytes to a file later.

```
Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath()))

Files.write(filename, message.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

Is there something else I need to do, maybe format related to make this work? The program consuming the message off the queue is giving me this error (after printing out the binary file)

```
is not a valid base64Binary.  A valid example is "AA==".
```

Comment: there might not be enough detail here to answer, but the error message "is not a valid base64Binary" indicates that maybe whatever printed that message is expected a base 64 encoded binary file,.  Base 64 is a way of encoding binary data in regular ASCII characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte[] buf = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
buf = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(buf);
```

This will base64 encode the bytes and may work better for you.

Comment: Do not use sun.misc.\* classes.  They can be removed in any future release of Java, and they won’t be usable by module-aware Java applications as of Java 9.  Use [java.util.Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) instead.